# Keyword execution not correct

Tags: python

For this repository I try to execute this command:

```
$ python feature_extraction.py -t 1 -i mairesse_Apache.arff
```

Here is the structure of the arff file I have
[image]
I receive this error:

```
Reading and cleaning emails corpus. Number of emails: 3
 Mails retrieved: 3
 Email addresses: 3
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "feature_extraction.py", line 64, in <module>
     main(sys.argv[1:])
   File "feature_extraction.py", line 39, in main
     ut.get_binary_scores(sorted(dict.keys()), str(task_num), str(task_num).join(score_file))
   File "C:\git\Personality-Recognition-in-SD\Utils.py", line 33, in get_binary_scores
     openness.append(p['openness'])
 KeyError: 'openness'
```

Here is the code from the repository for the util file (I post until the error line):

```
import json as js
import statistics
import pandas as pd
import os

with open('data/mailingList', 'r') as ml_file:
    ml = [line.strip() for line in ml_file]

with open('data/results-11-04-19.json') as result_file:
    result = js.load(result_file)

def get_mails():
    mails = []
    for p in result:
        time = sum(x * int(t) for x, t in zip([60, 1], p['time'].split(":")))
        if (time > 100 and not p['email'].strip()=='Anonymous User' and not p['email'].strip() in ml):
            mails.append(p['email'].strip())

    with open('data/lista_mail.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in mails:
            f.write(item + ', ')

    return mails

def get_binary_scores(mails, task_num, output_file):
    openness = []
    conscientiousness = []
    extraversion = []
    agreeableness = []
    neuroticism = []

    for p in result:
        openness.append(p['openness'])
        conscientiousness.append(p['coscientiousness'])
        extraversion.append(p['extraversion'])
        agreeableness.append(p['agreeableness'])
        neuroticism.append(p['neuroticism'])

    facts = {'1': 1, '2': 0.5, '3': 0}
    fact = facts[task_num]
```

What could it be wrong?

Should I change anything to the names?

mailcorpus.json file:

```
[
   {
      "id":12,
      "mailing_list_url":"12",
      "type_of_recipient":"From",
      "email_address":"test@test.org",
      "message_body":"Here is one text to test sentiment and feel happy",
      "is_response_of":"before"
   },
   {
      "id":21,
      "mailing_list_url":"21",
      "type_of_recipient":"From",
      "email_address":"test@gmail.com",
      "message_body":"Here is one text to test sentiment and feel happy and feel fine",
      "is_response_of":"before"
   },
   {
      "id":21,
      "mailing_list_url":"23",
      "type_of_recipient":"From",
      "email_address":"23@gmail.com",
      "message_body":"Not feel so good for this code",
      "is_response_of":"after"
   }
]
```

json file is the example file I used to reproduce the steps of repository

The link to the repository: https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD

Comment: It seems like in the file `data/results-11-04-19.json` you have an entry which does  not have `openness` as an attribute.

Comment: In this case, it might be helpful to see the contents of the `results-11-04-19.json` file. Otherwise, we'll just be guessing what's in that file.

Comment: @Thom from the instructions from the previous steps there was not produced any file with the name results-11-04-19.json so I changed it with the mailcorpus.json as in the edited code. Any idea how can I produce it?

Comment: @Nathalie there happens at `openness.append(p['openness'])` more specifically  on `p['openness']` because there is no `openness` attribute on `p`. Then we can see that `p` is an element of `result`. Then we can see that `result` is the JSON from `data/results-11-04-19.json`. So it means that the content from this file does  not have an `openness` attribute.

Comment: @Thom yes I can understand the result but from the instructions of the previous step in the repository I can't find the way to have this file. Any idea how can I make it?

Comment: @Nathalie Are you asking how to get the file `data/results-11-04-19.json`?

Comment: @Thom yes as this is the missing file. Thank you.

Comment: @Nathalie well, this is up to you. I don't know what you are trying to do with this script, but only you can find `data/results-11-04-19.json`.

Comment: a general thing: why do you define functions if they require variables to exist in the outer scope? e.g. `def get_mails()` only works because you create a variable `results` *before*.

Comment: @Thom I try to reproduce the previous steps and I have only the json I provide. Anything else is produced from the code I think

Comment: @MrFuppes I don't own the code. I just try to reproduce the steps with my mailcorpus.json file I provide

Comment: ok ;-) just saying, this coding style is pretty error-prone. the error you experience however is probably due to a missing key in the results json file as other commentators already noted.